# How to get the exception and to display the warning

Tags: python, qt, exception, pyqt

The code posted below creates a single dialog with a label and a button. Pressing button calls `calculate` function that raises `ZeroDivisionError` exception.

How to rewrite the code so `dialog` runs after `calculate` raises an exception. `dialog` would then set `label` to warning message.

```
app = QApplication([])

def divide():
    return 1 / 0

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.label = QLabel('Please press the button')
        button = QPushButton('Calculate')   
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClick)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout().addWidget(button)
        self.show()

    def onClick(self, text):
        divide()

dialog = Dialog()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you intercept the exception in `onClick` ? I am no expert in PyQt5 but I guess you can do something like:

```
class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.label = QLabel('Please press the button')
        button = QPushButton('Calculate')   
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClick)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout().addWidget(button)
        self.show()

    def onClick(self, text):
        try:
            divide()
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            self.label.setText("Error: there was a division by zero")
```

Intercepting the exception directly inside the `divide` method would be a bad idea in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Use try/except.

```
def onClick(self, text):
    try:
        divide()
    except Exception, e:
        print(e.massage)
```

Or replace

```
print(e.massage)
```

With whatever you want to do on exception/error.

If you want to only catch this specific type of error, use:

```
def onClick(self, text):
    try:
        divide()
    except ZeroDivisionError, e:
        print(e.massage)
```

Comment: How does your solution return the e.message back to `Dialog` so it can display it as a QLabel text?